# Loop through custom WP taxonomy, grab ACF field value for each

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I feel like I'm really close to a solution here, I'm just not familiar enough with php or wordpress syntax to see where I'm going wrong.

In the footer (used on every page on the site), I'd like to loop through a custom taxonomy I've created. Each taxonomy item has an acf color picker field. Each taxonomy item will be displayed on the site sin its own div with a border. I'd like to use the color value as the border color for each of the corresponding taxonomy divs.

the taxonomy: **topic**

the color picker field: **topic-color**

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
$topic = get_terms( 'topic', array('hide_empty' => true) );
$acftopic = get_field('topic');
foreach($topic as $topic) {
  $color = get_field('topic-color', $acftopic->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
  echo '<a class="topic-button" style="border-color:' . $color . ';"href="' . get_category_link($topic->term_id) . '">' . $topic->name . '</a>';
  }
?>
```

This gives me the divs with the taxonomy items in each, but the border color is just black for all of them: there's no value where the color should be. This is what each individual div looks like:

```
<a class="topic-button" style="border-color:;" href="http://detroitpeer.local/topic/literacy/">Literacy</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy'   => 'topic', //your taxonomy name
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
$acftopic = get_field('topic');

foreach($terms as $topic) {
  $color = get_field('topic-color', 'topic' . '_' . $topic->term_id);
  echo '<a class="topic-button" style="border-color:' . $color . ';"href="' . get_category_link($topic->term_id) . '">' . $topic->name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: hmmmmm no, that didn't do it

Comment: Okay, Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I have the border set in the styles.css file so I doubt this is it, but I'll try it out

Comment: No that's not it- the issue is that the color value isn't coming through. If you look at the html i linked in my original post, there's nothing in the style="border-color:" value. It's not that there's an issue with the border syntax, it's that there's nothing telling it which color to be.

Comment: I have reproduced your issue in my local to create a color picker with taxonomy. I made some changes and it's working fine. Please check my updated answer.